# Q: Using Certificate impacts Lightning Connect results

Tags: lightning-connect, certificates, deserialize

I have setup a Lightning Connect to provide reference access to data behind company firewall.  We use SOA Gateway tool to publish external web services (Odata 4.0 format), and I have been successful with retrieving data.  All connections had not been using Certificates but user/pwd for authentication.

Recently, SOA Gateway is configured to use Certificate for authentication. I changed the configuration to use a CA Certificate on the Lightning Connect object.  My request is submitted successfully, however, I get a "Cannot deserialize feed" error.  Interestingly, when I remove the certificate and retry pulling data from the external objects, I get the data from the source system.

Has anyone received similar errors using Lightning Connect and Certificates?  What did you do?  Thanks.